# Connection pooling and scaling of instances

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, database-connection, cloud-foundry

Note : This is a design related question to which i couldn't find a satisfying answer. Hence asking here.

I have a spring boot app which is deployed in cloud ( Cloud foundry). The app connects to an oracle database to retrieve data. The application uses a connection pool(HikariCp) to maintain the connections to database. Lets say the number of connections is set as 5. Now the application has the capacity to scale automatically based on the load. All the instances will be sharing the same database. At any moment there could 50 instances of the same application running, which means the total number of database connections will be 250 (ie 5 * 50).

Now suppose the database can handle only 100 concurrent connections. In the current scenario, 20 instances will use up  the 100 connections available. What will happen if the next 30 instances tries to connect to db? If this is design issue, how can this be avoided?

Please note that the numbers provided in the question are hypothetical for simplicity. The actual numbers are much higher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say:

- Number of available DB connections = `X`
- Number of concurrent instances of your application = `Y`
- Maximum size of the DB connection pool within each instance of your application = `X / Y`

That's slightly simplistic since you might want to be able to connect to your database from other clients (support tools, for example) so perhaps a safer formula is `(X * 0.95) / Y`.

Now, you have ensured that your application layer will not encounter 'no database connection exists' issues. However if `(X * 0.95) / Y` is, say, 25 and you have more than 25 concurrent requests passing through your application which need a database connection at the same time then some of those requests will encounter delays when trying to acquire a database connection and, if those delays exceed a configured timeout, they will result in failed requests.

If you can limit throughput in your application such that you will never have more than `(X * 0.95) / Y` concurrent 'get database connection' requests then hey presto the issue disappears. But, of course, that's not typically realistic (indeed since less is rarely more ... telling your clients to stop talking to you is generally an odd signal to send). This brings us to the crux of the issue:

> Now the application has the capacity to scale automatically based on the load.

Upward scaling is not free. If you want the same responsiveness when handling `N` concurrent requests as you have when handling `100000N` concurrent requests then something has to give; you have to scale up the resources which those requests need. So, if they make use of databaase connections then the number of concurrent connections supported by your database will have to grow. If server side resources cannot grow proprotional to client usage then you need some form of back pressure or you need to carefully manage your server side resources. One common way of managing your server side resources is to ...

- Make your service non-blocking i.e. delegate each client request to a threadpool and respond to the client via callbacks within your service (Spring facilitates this via DeferredResult or its Async framework or its RX integration)
- Configure your server side resources (such as the maximum number of available connections allowed by your DB) to match the maximum througput from your services based on the total size of your service instance's client-request threadpools

The client-request threadpool limits the number of currently active requests in each service instance it does **not** limit the number of requests your clients can submit. This approach allows the service to scale upwards (to a limit represented by the size of the client-request threadpools across all service instances) and in so doing it allows the service owner to safe guard resources (such as their database) from being overloaded. And since all client requests are accepted (and delegated to the client-request threadpool) the client requests are never rejected so it feels from their perspective as if scaling is seamless.

This sort of design is further augmented by a load balancer over the cluster of service instances which distributes traffic across them (round robin or even via some mechanism whereby each node reports its 'busy-ness' with that feedback being used to direct the load balancer's behaviour e.g. direct more traffic to NodeA because it is under utilised, direct less traffic to NodeB because it is over utilised).

The above description of a non blocking service only scratches the surface;  there's plenty more to them (and loads of docs, blog postings, helpful bits-n-pieces on the Internet) but given your problem statement (concern about server side resources in the face of increasing load from a client) it sounds like a good fit.